# ASP.NET impersonates NT AUTHORITY\IUSR but impersonation is disabled. ASP.NET bug?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, impersonation

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 application running on Windows 7 / IIS 7.5 in the "ASP.NET v4.0 Classic" application pool, which is configured to run as Network Service. The application has an `Application_EndRequest` handler which connects to a local SQL Server instance. The SQL connection string specifies `Integrated Security=SSPI`. Web.config does *not* have `<identity impersonate="true" />`.

When I browse to `http://localhost/TestSite/`, the following exception is thrown:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'.
   ...
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Global.Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

This exception is *not* thrown when I browse to `http://localhost/TestSite/default.aspx` (the default document configured in IIS) or any other .aspx page; in those cases the application correctly connects to SQL Server as "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE", which is a valid login.

**Why would ASP.NET impersonate "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR" in EndRequest even though impersonation is disabled? Is this a bug in ASP.NET?**

The following Global.asax.cs file demonstrates the problem:

```csharp
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    public Global()
    {
        this.BeginRequest += delegate { Log("BeginRequest"); };
        this.PreRequestHandlerExecute += delegate { Log("PreRequestHandlerExecute"); };
        this.PostRequestHandlerExecute += delegate { Log("PostRequestHandlerExecute"); };
        this.EndRequest += delegate { Log("EndRequest"); };
    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=.;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    private static void Log(string eventName)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        Type impersonationContextType = typeof(HttpContext).Assembly.GetType("System.Web.ImpersonationContext", true);
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("ThreadId={0} {1} {2} Impersonating={3}",
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            context.Request.Url,
            eventName,
            impersonationContextType.InvokeMember("CurrentThreadTokenExists", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, context, null)));
    }
}
```

Here's the trace output:

```
ThreadId=3 http://localhost/TestSite/ BeginRequest Impersonating=False
ThreadId=3 http://localhost/TestSite/ PreRequestHandlerExecute Impersonating=False
ThreadId=7 http://localhost/TestSite/default.aspx BeginRequest Impersonating=False
ThreadId=7 http://localhost/TestSite/default.aspx PreRequestHandlerExecute Impersonating=False
ThreadId=7 http://localhost/TestSite/default.aspx PostRequestHandlerExecute Impersonating=False
ThreadId=7 http://localhost/TestSite/default.aspx EndRequest Impersonating=False
ThreadId=7 http://localhost/TestSite/ PostRequestHandlerExecute Impersonating=True
ThreadId=7 http://localhost/TestSite/ EndRequest Impersonating=True
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'.
   ...
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Global.Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Note that a request to `TestSite/` (which is mapped to `DefaultHttpHandler`) seems to spawn a *nested* request to `TestSite/default.aspx` (which is mapped to `ASP.default_aspx`). After ASP.NET finishes processing `TestSite/default.aspx`, it impersonates "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR" when it resumes processing the request to `TestSite/`.

**UPDATE:** I've submitted this issue to [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/742531/asp-net-impersonates-nt-authority-iusr-but-impersonation-is-disabled).

Comment: try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998320.aspx

Comment: Which part? I already have Network Service set up in IIS and SQL Server.

Answer (score 32):

Most likely, the settings for your server, site or application are set so that "Anonymous Authentication" mode causes page requests to be handled as the IUSR user.  It doesn't matter that your application is not requesting impersonation; IIS is forcing it. (By the way, "impersonation" is generic  term in Windows-land for assuming another user's credentials.  It is not specific to ASP.NET.)

A bit of background:
For security reasons, IIS allows your server to field "anonymous" and "authenticated" requests under different system credentials.

Now, in IIS 7.5, if you have both anonymous authentication and Forms authentication enabled (which is typical), before your website user logs in via Forms, it considers your user "anonymous".  After your user logs in with Forms Auth, it considers your user "authenticated."

I found this behavior confusing at first because it's a change from IIS 6.0, which wasn't aware of Forms auth, and considered all Forms-Authenticated users to be anonymous!

If you want, you can change the identity under which  anonymous requests are fielded.  My preference (and it sounds like yours too) is that they run under the **same system credentials as my site's app pool.**  To make IIS do that, do the following:

1. Open the IIS Manager (inetmgr)
2. In the "Connections" panel, drill down to your site's node and select it
3. In the right-hand panel, under the "IIS" group, double click the "Authentication" icon.
4. Right-click on "Anonymous Authentication" and choose "Edit..." from the context menu.
5. In the popup dialog, select the **"Application pool identity"** radio button.
6. Click OK.

Step 5 also confused me at first, because I thought "application pool identity" meant "the application pool pseudo-account" (another new feature in IIS 7.5).  What it really means, of course, is **"the same account the app pool is configured to run under, whatever that is."**

If you want this behavior by default for all of your websites on that server, or even just single application under a particular site, you can configure the authentication options at those levels too.  Just select the node you want to configure in the Connections pane, then repeat steps 3-6.

Comment: This does not explain why .aspx requests are processed as NETWORK SERVICE from start to finish, whereas default document requests are processed as NETWORK SERVICE during the first part of the request life cycle and IUSR during the second part.

Comment: Does this explain why I've had to add both "IIS AppPool\<name>" AND "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR" security logins to my database?

Comment: I would upvote this several times, if I could. I can finally go to bed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Why would the application attempt to log in as "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR" even though the application is (probably) not using impersonation?**

If you do

```
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

it will impersonate the logged in user

If you do

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="contoso\Jane" password="pass"/>
```

it will impersonate the user set above.

But if you don't impersonate at all and use windows authentication, it would make sense that it uses a default system account.

I do not know why it makes the first attempt as IUSR and then automatically switches to NETWORK SERVICE on subsequent requests. But I do know that when you jump from one server to another, the application pool credenticals are NOT used. Unless you set an impersonated user as shown below, NETWORK SERVICE is default account that is used to fetch resources outside the server.

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MyServerName;Initial Catalog=MyDataBaseName;Integrated Security=True;"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>

<identity impersonate="true" userName="contoso\Jane" password="pass"/>
```

Comment: Both IIS and SQL Server are running on my development machine.